# Registering App For Location Intent-Filters

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app on the play store which shows users how to get around cities using different means of transport.

I want to register intent filters so users can open my app via other apps/websites. At the moment I have this intent filter defined.

```
    <activity android:name=".ui.activities.SearchActivity"
              android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="0">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="geo"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It works fine when I click on the address for a contact. My app shows up in the list. However when I click on an address in 4square the app does not show up in the list.

How can I insure that this works on all location clicks?

Answer (score 0):

So in the end it looks like the other apps are using google maps intent, you can define it like this.

```
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="maps.google.com" />
            <data android:scheme="geo"/>
        </intent-filter>
```